# What network protocol does python influxdb use to send data?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, influxdb, esp32

I'm interested in the answer to this question above because I'm trying to setup my Lab so I can send data from an ESP32 device over wifi to Influx DB hosted on my local network with a raspberry pi.

I've tried doing this with udp but the arduino libraries are very poorly documented (and didn't work)
and I couldn't find anything from Influx about what and how the data sending format should be...

Also is there a way to quickly find the network method used to transmit communicate with Python and influxDB?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/supported_protocols/) they support several methods.

Looking in particular to the [upd listener](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/supported_protocols/udp/) seems that you need to enable the listener on the influx db server first.

Comment: Ended up using the official arduino library for that it seems to work now after a fresh reinstall.